PostgreSQL Connection Issues: "remaining connection slots are reserved" & "Queue is bound to a different event loop" in Async Celery Task
Body:
I'm working on a project using PostgreSQL as the database and SQLAlchemy as the ORM. Recently, I've been encountering two issues related to database connections, particularly while running an async Celery task.
Issue 1: Connection Slots Exhaustion
Error:
An error occurred while fetching monitored positions: remaining connection slots are reserved for roles with privileges of the "pg_use_reserved_connections" role

Issue 2: Event Loop Binding
Error:
An error occurred while fetching monitored positions: <Queue at maxsize=25> is bound to a different event loop

Context:

Database: PostgreSQL
ORM: SQLAlchemy with async support
Task Queue: Celery
Command Used:

celery -A src.core.celery_app worker --loglevel=info -Q position_monitoring


Connection Pooling: Initially, I set up the connection pool with a high pool_size and max_overflow:

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

task_engine = create_async_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
    echo=True,
    pool_size=100,          # High pool size
    max_overflow=200        # High overflow
)

Issue Details:
1. Connection Slots Exhaustion:
The first error suggests that PostgreSQL has exhausted its available connection slots, and only users with specific privileges (those with the pg_use_reserved_connections role) can connect. This issue has been causing problems with tasks that need to query the database.
2. Event Loop Binding:
The second error indicates that a Queue object is being used across different event loops, which is causing issues with async task execution.
Task Code:
Here's the code for the Celery task that is causing these issues:
import gc
import logging
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from src.core.celery_app import celery_app
from src.database_tasks import TaskSessionLocal
from src.models.monitored_positions import MonitoredPosition
from src.services.trade_service import calculate_profit_loss, get_open_position
from src.utils.async_utils import run_async_in_sync
from src.utils.websocket_manager import websocket_manager

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@celery_app.task(name='src.tasks.position_monitor.monitor_positions')
def monitor_positions():
    gc.disable()
    logger.info("Starting monitor_positions task")
    run_async_in_sync(monitor_positions_async)

async def get_monitored_positions():
    try:
        logger.info("Fetching monitored positions from database")
        db: AsyncSession = TaskSessionLocal()
        result = await db.execute(select(MonitoredPosition))
        positions = result.scalars().all()
        db.close()
        logger.info(f"Retrieved {len(positions)} monitored positions")
        return positions
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred while fetching monitored positions: {e}")
        return []

async def monitor_positions_async():
    try:
        logger.info("Starting monitor_positions_async")
        positions = await get_monitored_positions()
        for position in positions:
            logger.info(f"Processing position {position.position_id}")
            await monitor_position(position)
        logger.info("Finished monitor_positions_async")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred in monitor_positions_async: {e}")

async def monitor_position(position):
    try:
        current_price = websocket_manager.current_prices.get(position.trade_pair)
        if current_price:
            profit_loss = calculate_profit_loss(
                position.entry_price,
                current_price,
                position.cumulative_leverage,
                position.cumulative_order_type,
                position.asset_type
            )
            if should_close_position(profit_loss, position):
                db: AsyncSession = TaskSessionLocal()
                await close_position(position)
                db.close()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred while monitoring position {position.position_id}: {e}")

async def close_position(position):
    try:
        db: AsyncSession = TaskSessionLocal()
        open_position = await get_open_position(db, position.trader_id, position.trade_pair)

        if open_position:
            close_submitted = await websocket_manager.submit_trade(position.trader_id, position.trade_pair, "FLAT", 1)
            if close_submitted:
                await db.execute(
                    text("DELETE FROM monitored_positions WHERE position_id = :position_id"),
                    {"position_id": position.position_id}
                )
                await db.commit()
        db.close()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred while closing position {position.position_id}: {e}")

def should_close_position(profit_loss, position):
    try:
        result = (
                (position.cumulative_order_type == "LONG" and profit_loss >= position.cumulative_take_profit) or
                (position.cumulative_order_type == "LONG" and profit_loss <= position.cumulative_stop_loss) or
                (position.cumulative_order_type == "SHORT" and profit_loss <= position.cumulative_take_profit) or
                (position.cumulative_order_type == "SHORT" and profit_loss >= position.cumulative_stop_loss)
        )
        logger.info(f"Determining whether to close position: {result}")
        # Enable the garbage collector
        gc.enable()
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred while determining if position should be closed: {e}")
        return False

this task runs every second.
from celery import Celery

celery_app = Celery(
    'core.celery_app',
    broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
    backend='redis://localhost:6379/0'
)

celery_app.conf.update(
    task_routes={
        'src.tasks.subscription_manager.manage_subscriptions': {'queue': 'subscription_management'},
        'src.tasks.subscription_manager.trade_pair_worker': {'queue': 'trade_pair_workers'},
        'src.tasks.position_monitor.monitor_positions': {'queue': 'position_monitoring'},
    },
    beat_schedule={
        'manage_subscriptions-every-10-seconds': {
            'task': 'src.tasks.subscription_manager.manage_subscriptions',
            'schedule': 10.0,  # every 10 seconds
        },
        'monitor_positions-every-1-second': {
            'task': 'src.tasks.position_monitor.monitor_positions',
            'schedule': 1.0,  # every 1 second
        },
    },
    timezone='UTC',
)

celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(['src.tasks'])

# Ensure tasks are loaded
import src.tasks.subscription_manager
import src.tasks.position_monitor

What I've Tried:
1. Lowering the Connection Pool Size:
I reduced the pool_size and max_overflow to more conservative values to limit the number of connections being opened at once:
task_engine = create_async_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
    echo=True,
    pool_size=5,          # Reduced pool size
    max_overflow=10       # Reduced overflow
)

2. Ensuring Proper Session Management:
I made sure that all database sessions are properly closed after use to prevent connection leaks:
sync def get_monitored_positions():
    try:
        logger.info("Fetching monitored positions from database")
        db: AsyncSession = TaskSessionLocal()
        result = await db.execute(select(MonitoredPosition))
        positions = result.scalars().all()
        db.close()
        logger.info(f"Retrieved {len(positions)} monitored positions")
        return positions
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred while fetching monitored positions: {e}")
        return []

3. Checking PostgreSQL Configuration:
I increased the max_connections setting in PostgreSQL by editing the postgresql.conf file from 100 to 200, but it didn't work too.
4. Event Loop Consistency:
I suspect that the event loop binding issue might be related to how tasks are being scheduled or executed in the application, possibly due to mismanagement of async tasks.
Questions:
1. Best Practices for Connection Pooling: Given the async nature of my application, what are the best practices for configuring connection pools in SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL? How should I balance pool_size and max_overflow?
2. Increasing max_connections: Is it advisable to increase the max_connections in PostgreSQL? What should I consider before doing this, and how do I determine the appropriate value?
3. Handling Event Loop Issues: How can I ensure that async tasks are consistently bound to the correct event loop? What might cause a Queue to be bound to a different event loop, and how can I resolve this?
4. Connection Pooling Middleware: Would using a tool like PgBouncer be beneficial in this scenario? How does it integrate with an async setup in SQLAlchemy?
5. Handling High Concurrency: My application occasionally needs to handle bursts of concurrent tasks. How can I manage database connections efficiently during these spikes without running into these issues?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
